# Security Issue for a user group in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, development, security

For a SharePoint group 'A', I made the security to Read only. Now my requirement is that,

I have created a custom webpart, with one text box and a button, Where the users from 'A' group was supposed to add data using it, And the data will be stored in a list from this webpart.

Since I made this group read only first time I got access denied message,

Hence I granted full control for this list for the group 'A', however even after giving full access to this list I am getting access denied messages for this group.

Plz help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the list inherits permissions from the site.  If not, you may have to update the list permissions manually.

Also confirm the credentials being used to update the list (via the webpart).

Comment: Hi Russell, Thank you for your help, The problem indeed was that, Some how the security added to the list after chnaging the inherit permission did not applay, Now everything works just perfect!!